# Create Istio Service Entry with Range in HELM Template

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I am creating 3 Istio service entries using HELM template.  When I use range it only create the last one. Here is the value.yaml and service entry yaml.  How do I create 3 service entries here?

```
serviceentry:
  appdb01: APPDB01.domain.com
  appdb02: APPDB02.domain.com
  appdb03: APPDB03.domain.com
```

```
{{- range $key, $val := .Values.serviceentry }}
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: ServiceEntry
metadata:
  name: {{ $key }}
  namespace: mytest
spec:
  hosts:
  -  {{ $val | quote }}
  location: MESH_EXTERNAL
  ports:
  - name: tcp1433
    number: 1433
    protocol: TCP
  - name: udp1434
    number: 1434
    protocol: UDP
  resolution: DNS
{{- end }}
```

Result:
Only the appdb03 is created

When running the HeLM template, it only creates the appdb03 but not the other 2.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure you include a YAML start-of-document marker, `---` on its own line, inside the `range` loop.  This is true whenever you're producing multiple Kubernetes manifests from the same Helm template file; it's not specific to this Istio use case.

```yaml
{{- range $key, $val := .Values.serviceentry }}
---
apiVersion: ...
{{- end }}
```